# MySQL exception during realtime update

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I've built a C# application that updates a MySQL db table every 10 ms.  The app creates a separate thread for each update.  Using Workbench, I can see that there are many connections and for a while, this has been quite successful.  Recently though, I find that after 2-3 hours of successful execution I am getting an exception which says "Table xxxx not found".  I have both a read and an update using Entity Framework, as follows

```
    try
    {
        u5s = (from u in cxt.universe5s
               where u.CATEGORY == tval
               select u).ToList();
        . . .
        u5.PC_CHANGE = chval;
        cxt.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception myEx)
    {
        //throws my 'table not found' exception here
    }
```

Using NET 4.0 and MySql 5.5.9.  Does anyone else have an experience like this?  Could it be caused by running out of connections?  What is the best practice in this case as far as closing the connection after saving changes?

Sincerely
Richard

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a concurrency issue. You might try to lock on a single connection object. That would also reduce the stress on the server.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: H'mm. I was depending on MySQL to sort out concurrency issues. I didn't want my locks to slow down access, but that makes less sense now that I'm generating a thread for each update. The link you gave is quite helpful, although I'm not sure what you mean by locking on a "connection object". Is that the db context "cxt" in my example code? So, would I wrap everything inside the try block with "lock (cxt) { ... }? The MSDN citation seems to emphasize using a private variable as a lock. I'm a bit ignorant as to what best serves as a lock object.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter, what object you lock on. Just make sure that every thread locks on the same one.

If you like you can create a dedicated object for the job: 

private object connectionLock = new object();

Comment: OK! Then it is just like the example you gave in the link. Thank you, I will implement it that way. I appreciate your help.  Sincerely, Richard